# How to select an image from retrieved data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm writing an html code to retrieve the details of the item table in my database.In it, I have some columns and one such column name is Image.It stores images of the Items and it's type is blob.I have written the following code to retrieve and display the data in this table in my php file.

```js
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item where item.Category = 'Tops' limit 3";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
      
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
  $id = $row["Item_ID"];
  echo " <div class='ite'>
  <div class='card'>
  <img src=".$row["Image"]." alt=".$row["Item_Name"]." class='imge'>
  <h3>".$row["Item_Name"]."</h3>
  <p class='price'>Rs. ".$row["Price"]."</p>
  <p><button type='submit' onclick='view_data($id)'>View Item</button></p>
  </div>
  </div>";
 }
}
```

The code works perfectly for the other columns except the image column(`<img src=".$row["Image"]." alt=".$row["Item_Name"]." class='imge'>`)

The output is as follows.

[image]

It gives garbage values like this.How can I fix this error and display the image stored in the database?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' .  base64_encode($row['Image'])  . '" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($row['Image']) . "' class='imge'>
```

This works!Thanks for the support!